# Django catches wrong url, have to fix regex

Tags: django

I ended up like 
www.ww.mywebsite.com/ urls with google search results,

I asked in google groups and They pointed the obvious that, www.ww.mywebsite.com, shouldnt be a 200 ok response.

`(r'^$', myview)`, this is how I catch a url for my homepage,

I dont think this problem occurs cause of my url patterns cause, as far as I know, url patterns for to catch trailing words. www.wwww.example.com/test/, there would be 'test' to be our word to process, what about this wwww staff before my website name?

Comment: You have to end you regex with a slash before dollar sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fully qualified URL `www.example.com/test/`, the Django URL matching only looks at the `/test/` part. Here you need to filter the domain names, for which the [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) setting was introduced. For example you can put in `settings.yml`:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mywebsite.com', 'www.mywebsite.com']
```

Alternatively, you can use a custom middleware to redirect the user to the canonical URL. This is a better solution if the non-canonical URLs should still be accessible to the users:

```
class CanonicalDomainRedirectMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.get_host() == 'mywebsite.com':
            return None
        if request.is_secure():
            protocol = 'https'
        else:
            protocol = 'http'
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('%s://%s/%s' % (
            protocol, 'mywebsite.com', request.get_full_path)
```

Comment: If I do that, django will throw a lot of errors for users who still tries www.wwwww.example.com, Cause google has indexed that pages already, U know a way to 301 permanent redirect from ww.wwww.example.com like urls to www.example.com url?